# Ubuntu touchscreen not working after some restarts

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, 16.10, touchscreen

I installed Ubuntu 16.10 (and also 16.04 previously) on dual-boot with Windows 10. Touchscreen of my laptop worked fine after installation.

It worked until 2-3 restarts after installation but suddenly stopped. After that issue I always get a `device descriptor read error/64, error -32` message on startup. Although that does not have any effect on overall performance of the system, but the touchscreen problem persists. I did a lot of things firstly installed Ubuntu 16.04 and then 16.10 (hoping the problem would be fixed), updated the kernel to 4.9.5 (as it had added amdgpu support).

The touchscreen is an ELAN Touchscreen. It is a usbtouchscreen. Surprisingly after the issue it does not show up in "lsusb" and neither in xinput (It did show up before the issue on both xinput and lsusb)

```
    alphaq@alphaq:~$lsusb
    $Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1bcf:289b Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
    $Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card $Reader Controller
    $Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
    $Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    $Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    $Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

"xinput" has the following output :

```
    alphaq@alphaq:~$ xinput
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
        ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Integrated Webcam                         id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Although the Elan Touchscreen shows up in dmesg | grep input

```
    alphaq@alphaq:~$ dmesg | grep input
    [   82.411726] input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/0003:04F3:0034.0002/input/input15
    [   82.415976] hid-multitouch 0003:04F3:0034.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [ELAN Touchscreen] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6/input0
```

I am also providing the output of "dmesg | grep usb" as it has some interesting result

```
    alphaq@alphaq:~$ dmesg | grep usb
    [   81.753237] usb 1-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 30 using ehci-pci
    [   81.833246] usb 1-1.6: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    [   82.021259] usb 1-1.6: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    [   82.209266] usb 1-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 31 using ehci-pci
    [   82.248373] usb 1-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=0034
    [   82.248378] usb 1-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=14, SerialNumber=0
    [   82.248381] usb 1-1.6: Product: Touchscreen
    [   82.248384] usb 1-1.6: Manufacturer: ELAN
    [   82.411726] input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/0003:04F3:0034.0002/input/input15
    [   82.415976] hid-multitouch 0003:04F3:0034.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [ELAN Touchscreen] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6/input0
    [   88.745661] usb 1-1.6: reset full-speed USB device number 31 using ehci-pci
    [   94.041261] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
    [   95.197961] usb 1-1.6: reset full-speed USB device number 31 using ehci-pci
    [   95.281930] usb 1-1.6: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    [   95.469954] usb 1-1.6: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    [   95.657930] usb 1-1.6: reset full-speed USB device number 31 using ehci-pci
    [   95.737942] usb 1-1.6: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    [   95.925974] usb 1-1.6: device descriptor read/64, error -32
    [   96.117999] usb 1-1.6: reset full-speed USB device number 31 using ehci-pci
```

then the same lines keep repeating forever. It seems like the touchscreen was detected by the system at some point of time but then it again lost connection. Surprisingly because of this i can't use the touchscreen in windows either...which i was able to use earlier before dual-boot.

I think I have provided enough details...but if anyone needs anything else  then please feel free to ask and "PLEASE HELP" ;)